# WM_COPYDATA struct content goes missing when restarting PC

Tags: c++, mfc, wm-copydata

I need some help regarding this bug as I can't figure out what's the cause of my `WM_COPYDATA` struct data going missing. Every time the computer is restarted, I'll be able to receive the message but with empty data. In order to fix it, I'll end all the related processes manually and restart them manually. Only then it works fine again. Next time PC restarts, same thing happens.

This is the function in a dll that sends the message. Another EXE will be calling this function
[image]
So basically, the data that is missing is the one boxed in red. 1002 however can be received on the other end.

Here's the receiving end from V4_APP exe
[image]

[image]

It will be able to enter this section, but strBatchValues will be empty.

Sorry for I know this may not be adequate information. Please let me know if you need any more details. I'm just trying to garner some insights if anyone has encountered such a situation before. I would appreciate any sort of help. Thanks in advance!

Code Test Below:

[Function in DLL, will be called by another EXE]

```
int TSECSData::NewBatch(CString strBatchValues)
{
    HWND hWnd = ::FindWindow(NULL, V4_APP);
    if(hWnd)
    {
        COPYDATASTRUCT cpd;
        char szDataToSend[256];
        sprintf_s(szDataToSend, "%S", strBatchValues);

        cpd.dwData = 1002;
        cpd.cbData = sizeof(szDataToSend);
        cpd.lpData = (void*)&szDataToSend;
        ::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, NULL,(LPARAM)&cpd);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

[Receiving portion in V4_APP]

```
BOOL CMainFrame::OnCopyData(CWnd* pWnd, COPYDATASTRUCT* pCopyDataStruct)
{
    int nMsg = (int)(pCopyDataStruct->dwData);
    if(nMsg==1000)
    {
        CString strRecipe;
        strRecipe.Format(_T("%S"),  pCopyDataStruct->lpData);
        theApp.OnAutoLoadRecipe(strRecipe);
    }
    else if(nMsg == 1002)
    {
        CString strBatchValues;
        strBatchValues.Format(_T("%S"), pCopyDataStruct->lpData);
        CWnd* ptr = CWnd::GetLastActivePopup();
        if(ptr == m_StartupPointer)       //Confirmation if there are no opened dialogs
        {
            m_MainPane.NewEndLot(strBatchValues);      //Batch only when enabled, else do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            BOOL bIsItModeless = m_StartupPointer->IsWindowEnabled();
            if(bIsItModeless)
                m_MainPane.NewEndLot(strBatchValues);    //Batch if any pop up dialog is modeless
        }
    }
    return CFrameWndEx::OnCopyData(pWnd, pCopyDataStruct);
}
```

Comment: Passing a `CString` variable to a variadic function like `sprintf_s` can be dangerous.  Cast the CString to `PCTSTR` to make sure you're getting a pointer to characters.

Comment: Please do not post images of code.  Post the actual text.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The situation makes perfect sense. Data doesn't persist through a PC restart, unless the app actively persists it, such as by saving it in a file, a database, the Registry, etc, and then loading it back on restart. This is normal behavior, not a bug. Also, the data passed in WM_COPYDATA is temporary, it is gone after the message is handled. So the receiver is responsible for making a copy of the data and saving it as needed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just added in the text, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry I did not elaborate on the sending portion. I've another app which is calling NewBatch() function again to resend the data. So in this case, I'm unsure why the data isn't going through. I'm wondering if there's maybe a linking error between the DLL and both the receiver and sender EXE? As when I restart the softwares, it works again.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks! I'll add on these improvements.

Comment: @Han what do you mean by "*the data isn't going through*"? It is not possible for WM_COPYDATA is lose data in flight, so something else is going on. Also, consider getting rid of the `char[]` buffer altogether and just send the `CString` data directly, ie: `char* pszDataToSend = (char*)strBatchValues; COPYDATASTRUCT cpd; cpd.dwData = 1002; cpd.cbData = strlen(pszDataToSend); cpd.lpData = pszDataToSend;` ... `CString strBatchValues((char*)pCopyDataStruct->lpData, pCopyDataStruct->cbData);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau casting to `char *` isn't going to work, you need to cast to `const TCHAR *` which `CString` has a conversion operator for.  And the buffer might be necessary if you're doing a conversion between wide and narrow characters.

Comment: @MarkRansom `CString` has a conversion to `char*`. Of course, it is lossy for non-ASCII characters. But `TCHAR*` is a bad choice for interprocess communications. There is no guarantee both programs are using the same data type for `TCHAR`. Better to use a standardize encoding, like UTF-8 or UTF-16 instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it's been quite a few years since I used CString, so maybe it changed.  But it's based on TCHAR, you need to use CStringA or CStringW if you want to avoid that.  Totally agree on the necessity of standardizing an encoding that both sides use consistently.

Comment: @MarkRansom you are right, I misread it. `CString` is `TCHAR` only, use `CStringA` for `char` or `CStringW` for `wchar_t`